# How can I configure CMake to generate a buildsystem that emits colored errors and warnings?

Tags: c++, shell, cmake

Is there a way to produce colorful output (like diagnostic messages and status messages) from tools in a CMake-generated buildsystem like `gcc` and `make`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want colourful output from `cmake` binary? For that I don't know any solution.

`CMake` can generate `Makefiles` that provide [verbose (and colourful)](http://www.console-colors.de/images/screenshot-colormake.png) information about the build process. This can be enabled in the following way:

```
SET(CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE ON)
# And optionally
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

If you want to have the `gcc` output colourised, then have a look at [`colorgcc`](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html) perl script. Having it installed try something like this:

```
CC=/usr/bin/colorgcc cmake .....
```

Or use the newer solution proposed in another answer by [gfour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671119/gfour) - the [gccfilter](https://github.com/licheng/gccfilter/blob/master/gccfilter)

Comment: Thanks, verbose flag does work. It added this to Makefile: `+# Produce verbose output by default.
+VERBOSE = 1
+` but no coloring. I have `cmake version 2.8.5`

Comment: Check in `CMakeCache.txt`, whether `CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=OFF` or `ON`

Comment: yes, I have it `ON` and coloring for `cmake` command works. Maybe I should rephrase the question, I would like to have colors in `gcc` output or whichever compiler is called from `cmake`

Comment: @Tombart: Altered the answer to address your problem.

Comment: thanks, I couldn't make it work I'm compiling it with `c++` which is just a softlink to `g++-4.6`. `gccfilter` suggested by @gfour works fine

Answer (score 8):

Since CMake v3.24, there is [the `CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS.html). Follow that link for the most up-to-date version of the docs. Here is a quote from the 3.24.2 docs:

> Enable color diagnostics throughout.
>
> This variable uses three states: `ON`, `OFF` and not defined.
>
> When not defined:
>
> - [Makefile Generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#makefile-generators) initialize the [`CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE.html#variable:CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE) variable to `ON`. It controls color buildsystem messages.
> - GNU/Clang compilers are not invoked with any color diagnostics flag.
>
> When `ON`:
>
> - [Makefile Generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#makefile-generators) produce color buildsystem messages by default. [`CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE.html#variable:CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE) is not initialized, but may be explicitly set to `OFF` to disable color buildsystem messages.
> - GNU/Clang compilers are invoked with a flag enabling color diagnostics (`-fcolor-diagnostics`).
>
> When `OFF`:
>
> - [Makefile Generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#makefile-generators) do not produce color buildsystem messages by default. [`CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE.html#variable:CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE) is not initialized, but may be explicitly set to `ON` to enable color buildsystem messages.
> - GNU/Clang compilers are invoked with a flag disabling color diagnostics (`-fno-color-diagnostics`).
>
> If the [`CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS.html#envvar:CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS) environment variable is set, its value is used. Otherwise, `CMAKE_COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS` is not defined by default.

Comment: Should be top voted option in 2022

Answer (score 5):

Other tools are not necessary now. GCC and Clang produce color output but hide it when they detect they're being used in a pipeline like CMake Makefiles use. They have flags to force color though.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    add_compile_options(-fdiagnostics-color=always)
elseif("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
    add_compile_options(-fcolor-diagnostics)
endif()
```

If you *do* pipe the output of make sometimes, you can put this behind a flag.

Color output preview:

[image: Example color output]

Reference:
https://medium.com/@alasher/colored-c-compiler-output-with-ninja-clang-gcc-10bfe7f2b949

Answer (score 3):

Download [gccfilter](https://github.com/licheng/gccfilter/blob/master/gccfilter) (needs perl, libregexp and libgetopt-argvfile), then run:

> gccfilter -c cmake ...

This will colorize the messages from the build process (which I assume are gcc mesages).

Comment: Works nice, thanks! Although it cancels colors from cmake messages

Answer (score 3):

Try [colout](http://nojhan.github.io/colout/), it is designed to seamlessly color the output of any command, and comes with a *g++* AND a *cmake* theme, which you can use together:

```
make something 2>&1 | colout -t cmake | colout -t g++
```

Besides improving the cmake colorscheme, it even applies **syntax coloring** on the code printed out by g++.

Comment: very good! No need for symlinks here. You just add the color when you actually want it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this discussion](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Cmake-coloring-gcc-output-on-errror-td7173100.html) I've created an alias in `~/.bashrc` for `make`:

```
alias make="make VERBOSE=1 2>&1 | sed -e 's%^.*: error: .*$%\x1b[37;41m&\x1b[m%' -e 's%^.*: warning: .*$%\x1b[30;43m&\x1b[m%'"
```

it's not really nice solution, but it does the job.